# Google action "isn't responding right now" after account linking completed

Tags: actions-on-google, diagflow

Im developing a google action with account linking.

When a new user does an initial request to my action, I get it over the webhook and respond with the SIGN_IN response. The assistant asks the user to link the account. The users does so, and the action then reports "XXX isn't responding right now", yet there were no further webhook requests to respond to. There is nothing in the logs viewer other than the initial request.

The next request by the user works fine, indicating that account linking did indeed complete. How can I avoid this error to the user??

Comment: Can you access user's information in your webhook after account linking is complete?

Comment: Yes, further requests include the access token from the linking. I believe the skill leaves the conversation after the error, but when reinvoked it has the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because you either have no Intent in Dialogflow which can handle the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event or you have one and it is not set to do webhook fulfillment and returns no response.

Comment: Thanks, I added that action to an existing welcome intent and it does seem to solve the problem. It does not match to any of the google autocomplete built in actions in diagflow but did work.